# Martian dust storms-what was the smallest in area, or shortest in duration storm detected?

Tags: mars, dust-storm

I understand localized Martian dust storms can develop into global wide events. All searches I do produce results that focus on local storms expanding.  Is there any information on what was the shortest duration or smallest area dust storm recorded?

Comment: What do you consider a "dust storm?"  Dust devils are on the scale of meters.

Comment: Didn't know dust devils were considered storms. Researching this lead to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SOLAR SYSTEM/SUN, ATMOSPHERES, EVOLUTION OF ATMOSPHERES | Planetary Atmospheres](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/physics-and-astronomy/dust-storms)

> Numerous dust storms occur each Martian year and are generally classified according to size. From the smallest to largest, they are dust devils (<10<sup>−1</sup> km<sup>2</sup>), local storms (∼10<sup>3</sup> km<sup>2</sup>), regional storms (∼10<sup>6</sup> km<sup>2</sup>), and planet-encircling storms (>10<sup>6</sup> km<sup>2</sup>).
>
> Local dust storms are also quite common. Based on Mars Global Surveyor (MGS) images, as many as 2000 local storms occur each Martian year. This gives a daily-averaged rate of 2–3 storms per Martian day. They have typical lifetimes of less than several days.
>
> Regional storms have been observed at nearly all seasons, but are most frequent during southern spring and summer. Most regional storms develop within ±30° of latitude, although there is a distinct bias toward the southern hemisphere. Regional storms can last from days to weeks. These storms can drift a significant distance from their original location, and new satellite storms can develop that are quite remote from the original center.